# WPF Binding ObservableCollection to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I try to bind a list of Lens Objects and I would like to display the LensName property in my combobox.My lists in my code contain objects but comboboxes remain empty or the property doesn't display.I already tried all the  ways known to bind my data without result.Thanks for helping

Xaml

```xml
<ComboBox  x:Name="RightbestlensCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=RightBestLensList}" DisplayMemberPath="LensName" SelectedValuePath="LensTypeId" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="LeftbestlensCombo"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source=LefttBestLensList}" DisplayMemberPath="LensName" SelectedValuePath="LensTypeId"  ></ComboBox>
```

Code Behind

```cs
      public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> RightBestlensList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();
        public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> LeftBestlensList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();


 if (OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.LeftBestLensList != null)
                {
                    if (OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.LeftBestLensList.Count > 0)
                    {        
                        LeftBestlensList=new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>(OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.LeftBestLensList);
                    //LeftbestlensCombo.ItemsSource = LeftBestlensList;

                    }
                }

                if (OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.RightBestLensList != null)
                {
                    if (OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.RightBestLensList.Count > 0)
                    {
                         RightBestlensList=new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>(OphtalboxIA.OphtalboxComputingModule.RightBestLensList);
                       //RightbestlensCombo.ItemsSource = RightBestlensList;

                    }
                }
```

My class Lens

```cs
 [XmlInclude(typeof(Lens))]
    public class Lens{

        public String LensName;
        public String LensType;
        public String LensTypeTrial;
        public float Diameter;
        public float Radius;
        public float Sphere;
        public float Cylinder;
        public int Axis;
        public String Addition;
        public String Description;
        public int isRX;
        public int isOphtalBox;
        public int priorityOrder;
        public int LensFrequencyId;
        public string LensFrequencyName;
        public int LensTypeId;
        public int LensMaterialId;
        }
```

Comment: are the properties get populated after binding? if so then the reason is that your `Lens` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. that is required to push values to view, in this case ComboBox needs that interface to be implemented in order to get notified of any change in value so that it can pull them to view.

Comment: No the properties are already populated...and then I do the binding...

Answer (score 1):

You need properties, not fields. These are fields:

```
public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> RightBestlensList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();
public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> LeftBestlensList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();
```

As properties, they would look like this:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> _rightList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();
private readonly ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> _leftList = new ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens>();

public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> RightBestlensList { get { return _rightList; }}
public ObservableCollection<OphtalboxIA.Lens> LeftBestlensList { get { return _leftList; }}
```

Furthermore, you have a typo in your binding: `Source=LefttBestLensList`. (One extra "t") And the casing is wrong ("...Lens..." vs. "...lens...").

Answer (score 0):

`RightBestlensList` and `LeftBestlensList` must be in ViewModel class and not in Code Behind and they must be a properties.

Comment: Why take the time to answer a question, but put so little effort into it? Have you not seen the usual high quality answers that are provided at Stack overflow? Why would you spoil that with your single sentence answer that could just as well have been a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to try below menioned code.

you have to Declare ObservableCollection in your ViewModel Like

```
 private ObservableCollection<Lens> _RightBestLensList = new ObservableCollection<Lens>();

    public ObservableCollection<Lens> RightBestLensList
    {
        get { return _RightBestLensList; }
        set { _RightBestLensList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("RightBestLensList"); }
    }
```

Your Lens Class Should be

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Lens))]
public class Lens
{
    public string LensName { get; set; }
    public string  LensType { get; set; }

}
```